# Google Maps - addGeoJson is not working for my file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

addGeoJson is not working in google map for my file

please check below code that I am using in javascript

```
//create the map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
   zoom: 6,
   center: {lat:49.79, lng: -8.82}
});

// Load GeoJSON.
var promise = $.getJSON("Sensitive_Areas_Nitrates_Rivers.json"); //same as map.data.loadGeoJson();
promise.then(function(data){
    cachedGeoJson = data; //save the geojson in case we want to update its values
    console.log(cachedGeoJson);
    map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson,{idPropertyName:"id"});  
});
```

I have downloaded this file from [here](https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?mapService=EA/SensitiveAreasNitratesRivers&Mode=spatial)

you can check my JSON file 
[Sensitive_Areas_Nitrates_Rivers.json](https://gunroom-admin.eliteevince.com/json/Sensitive_Areas_Nitrates_Rivers.json)

also, you can check this [link](https://environment.data.gov.uk/farmers/)  with polygon

I have used below JSON format so you can check it

> {
>         "type": "FeatureCollection",
>         "crs": {
>           "type": "name",
>           "properties": {
>             "name": "EPSG:27700"
>           }
>         },
>         "features": [
>           {
>             "type": "Feature",
>             "id": 1,
>             "geometry": {
>               "type": "MultiLineString",
>               "coordinates": [
>                 [
>                   [
>                     500051.6875,
>                     224280.03130000085
>                   ],
>                   [
>                     500047.2812999999,
>                     224277.6875
>                   ],
>                   [
>                     499977.5937999999,
>                     224242.625
>                   ],
>                   [
>                     499976.6875,
>                     224242.21880000085
>                   ]
>                 ]
>               ]
>             },
>             "properties": {
>               "OBJECTID": 8,
>               "type_of_sa": "SA_N",
>               "datedesign": 1025136000000,
>               "name": "Rivers Itchen",
>               "length_km": 12,
>               "uwwtd_code": "UKENRI134",
>               "shape_Length": 12172.080443901654
>             }
>           }
>         ]
>       }

[500051.6875, 224280.03130000085] - [X, Y] coordinates may be in EPSG: 27700 to EPSG:4326, Now we need to display these coordinates on google map, Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Maps expects GeoJSON to be in `EPSG:4326`, `Sensitive_Areas_Nitrates_Rivers.json` needs to be reprojected. [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/), for instance, could be utilized for that matter (refer [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html?highlight=reprojecting) for a details)

[image]

[image]

Reprojected `Sensitive_Areas_Nitrates_Rivers.json` layer will be displayed like this:

[image]

Comment: I want to display all the coordinates in my project using map.data.loadGeoJson('Features.geojson') function and browser are crashed if there is any big file so Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting coordinates in metres. For displaying in google map you need to convert it into [Lng, Lat].

For converting metres to [Lng, Lat] you need to change the projection from EPSG: 27700 to 4326
then only you are able to get this geojson in [Lng, Lat]

Tool you can use: QGIS Desktop 3.4.14
Link: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

After convert you need to export this file as feature.